# Missing Right Parenthesis in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to learning SQL. When I create this table, it has an Asterix (*) under the first parenthesis of the "(dbClassID)" and says "missing right parenthesis"

Does anyone know why it does that and how I can fix it?

```
CREATE TABLE vod_classification (
dbClassId               CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
dbDescription           VARCHAR2(100)
CONSTRAINT vod_classification_PK PRIMARY KEY (dbClassId)
);
```

Comment: Try adding a `,` (comma) after `VARCHAR2(100)`

Comment: Also, `CHAR(4)` should probably be `VARCHAR2(4)` unless there is an actual business requirement to blank-pad shorter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CONSTRAINT](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj24513.html) is part of table creation and need to be comma delimited as other column:

```
CREATE TABLE zz_classification (
dbClassId               CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
dbDescription           VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT vod_classification_PK PRIMARY KEY( dbClassId)
);
```

> Tables contain columns and constraints

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the help! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing , here try this VARCHAR2(100),

Answer (score 0):

For a single-column constraint, it's neater to define it inline as part of the column:

```
create table vod_classification
( dbclassid        varchar2(4)   not null constraint vod_classification_pk primary key
, dbdescription    varchar2(100) not null constraint vod_classification_uk unique
);
```

I have corrected the `CHAR` column to the standard string type which is `VARCHAR2` in Oracle.

(PK columns will be `not null` automatically, but I've left it in for completeness and in case you later `create table as select`.)

Answer (score 0):

When using the "Create" code, you must use a comma in the line where you define each column of the table. Except the last column. You can read the oracle sql syntax link as follows: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr01001.htm#SQLQR110